# Throw an exception from a Vue component and prevent any further processing

Tags: vuejs2

I’m writing Vue components and I would like to throw an exception when one of the properties are missing or invalid, also, I would like to prevent Vue from rendering the template and stop any further processing to a point where the template won't be rendered and finally added to the DOM.

**So here is a slimmed down version of one of the components I wrote:**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
    components: {}
})
export default class Checkbox extends Vue {
    @Prop() public id?: string;

    public mounted() {
        if (this.id == null) {
            this.$el.remove();
            throw new Error("The id property is missing.");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now, this works but it has a drawback because it requires removal of the element from the DOM and this makes testing harder for the following reasons:

1. When the component is mounted without an id it throws an exception, as I intended.
2. Because I throw an exception from the `mounted` lifecycle hook method I can't mount the component and get an instance to check whether the element was removed and to an extent this doesn't make sense to me.

**Here is the actual test:**

```
describe("When the id property is not assigned", () => {
    it("then the checkbox should throw an exception", () => {
        expect(() => shallowMount(Checkbox)).to.throw(); // works fine as expected.
    });

    it("then the checkbox should not exist", () => {
        const wrapper: VueWrapper = shallowMount(Checkbox); // throws because we didn't provide any id, again, as expected.

        /* This is what I would like to do but I don't get an instance back so obviously I can't do it. */
        const checkbox = wrapper.vm.$el; 
        expect(checkbox).to.not.exist;
    });
});
```

I’ve tried to throw the exception from the `created` lifecycle hook method as opposed to `mounted` but it doesn’t stop Vue from adding the element to the DOM.

Just to clarify I wrote in the test that "this is what I would like to do" but really what I would prefer is not to remove the element at all and prevent any insertion of the rendered component into the DOM, this way I wouldn't even need to test for it.

Comment: Did you try throwing an exception in a custom validator. Not sure if it would work, but it seems like it would, assuming you only want to keep the invalid component from rendering in an invalid state. Or you could redirect to an error page.

Comment: It was long time ago so I can't remember the exact details but I tried a lot of stuff and I'm pretty sure custom validators are mainly used for input validation (could be wrong though) and don't prevent the element itself from being rendered in the case of an error so the element would still exist in the DOM, redirecting would make it harder to test and it isn't really what I wanted, the accepted answer allowed me to separate the concerns and test each state of the component in isolation, meaning, when the component is rendered successfully and when exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous attempts were bad because they didn't work well across components or an overkill but the following approach worked like a charm for me.

I've created a custom exception class called `DismountException` which looks something like this:

```
import { Exception } from "./exception";

export class DismountException extends Exception {
    constructor(public readonly element: HTMLElement, message: string) {
        super(message);
        element.remove();
    }
}
```

This separation of concerns allows me to test the exception separately from any component and check whether an element is removed from the DOM when the exception is created as a result it makes the components easier to test, I'd only need to test whether they throw the exception.

As a side note because the logic to remove the element is centralized in the exception, one can go further with this idea and add flags to dictate the behaviour of the exception when is thrown on a per component basis.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this to work the way I want by overriding `errorHandler` like this:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
    console.error(info);
    console.error(err);
    if (vm.$options != null && vm.$options.props != null && vm.$el instanceof HTMLElement) {
        for (const key in vm.$options.props) {
            if (vm.$options.props.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const prop = (vm.$options.props as any)[key];
                if (prop.required) {
                    vm.$el.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The implementation of the checkbox looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Checkbox extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    public id?: string;

    public mounted() {
        if (this.id == null) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
</script>
```

And finally because removing the element is no longer the concern of the component the test was simplified and looks like this:

```
describe("When the id property is not assigned", () => {
    it("then the checkbox should throw an exception", () => {
        expect(() => shallowMount(Checkbox)).to.throw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous solution was an overkill and I was really overthinking so what I ended up doing is removing the element when the required property isn't provided like so:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Checkbox extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    public id?: string;

    public mounted() {
        if (this.id == null) {
            this.$el.remove();
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally the tests I wrote for it are as follow:

```
describe("When the id property is not provided", () => {
    let wrapper: VueWrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(Checkbox, {
            attachToDocument: true
        });
    });

    it("and is required", () => {
        const id = (wrapper.vm.$options.props as any).id;
        expect(id.required).to.be.true;
    });

    it("then the input element should not exist in the DOM", () => {
        const exists = document.body.contains(wrapper.element);
        expect(exists).to.be.false;
    });
});
```